# Mysql how to flatten a result set

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure that will return a list of ids. I want to return that list as a comma separated string, i.e. "1,2,3,4,5".

I know I can do this using a cursor but is there an easier way to turn a resultset into a flattened string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MySQL has the [group_concat() aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT group_concat(some_column) FROM mytable;
```

Will return all `some_column` values from table joined by commas.

**Caveat:** Beware that the result is limited by the `group_concat_max_len` system variable, which defaults to only 1024 bytes! To avoid hitting this wall, you should execute this before running the query:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 65536;
```

Or more, depending on how many results you expect. But this value *cannot* be larger than `max_allowed_packet`

Answer (score 1):

```
select group_concat(id) from table
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score -3):

You should really do formatting in the external code.